# Let $g(x) = \int_{0}^{2^x} \sin(t^2)\,dt $. What is the $g'(0)$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm kinda stuck in this exercise :

> Let $\displaystyle g(x) = \int_{0}^{2^x}\sin{(t^2)\,dt}$. What is the $g'(0)$?

How do I approach this kind of thing? I was thinking about Riemann sums but does this have any application here?

Comment: No. Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Consider $$h(x)=\int_0^x \sin(t^2)\,dt.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Let $F(t)$ be an antiderivative of $\sin(t^2)$. We will not find an explicit formula for $F(t)$, but we won't need to.

We have
$$g(x)=F(2^x)-F(0).$$
Differentiate, using the Chain Rule. Note that since $2^x=e^{x\ln 2}$, the derivative of $2^x$ is $(\ln 2)e^{x\ln 2}=(\ln 2)2^x$.
It follows that
$$g'(x)=(\ln 2)2^x F'(2^x).$$
But $F'(2^x)=\sin((2^x)^2)=\sin(2^{2x})$. Putting things together, we find that
$$g'(x)=(\ln 2)2^x\sin(2^{2x}).$$

One can write the above argument more compactly. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we have for any continuous function $f(t)$, that the derivative of $\int_a^u f(t)\,dt$ with respect to $u$ is $f(u)$. Letting $u=2^x$, and $a=0$, we find that 
$$g(x)=\int_a^u \sin(t^2)\,dt.$$
Then
$$\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{dg}{du}\frac{dg}{dx}.$$
But $\frac{dg}{du}=\sin(u^2)$ and $\frac{du}{dx}=(\ln 2)2^x$, and we are essentially finished.

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure, I have another exercise on this : $g(x) = \int_{e\cdot x}^{e^2\cdot x}\sqrt{\ln(t)}dt$ for $x>1$. Find $g'(e)$. So I followed these steps and got $g'(x) = \sqrt{\ln(e^2\cdot x)}\cdot e^2 - \sqrt{\ln(e\cdot x)}\cdot e$ is this correct? :)

Comment: If you typed the problem correctly, then yes, it is correct. But since they are asking for the derivative **at** $x=e$, you need to evaluate your expression at $x=e$. The $\ln$ of $e^2 x$ will then be $3$, the $\ln$ of $ex$ will be $2$, and we end up with $\sqrt{3}e^2-\sqrt{2}e$. A similar remark applies to your original problem. The question asked about $g'(0)$. I found a general expression for $g'(x)$, and you need to put $x=0$ in the expression I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

$g'(x)= 2^x \sin ((2^x)^2)\ln 2$

For more information you can refer to this [Differentiation of integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Comment: I think it's most likely that the OP doesn't know about the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part).

Comment: I have posted the above link under the assumption that he knows it.

Comment: Yes, that's why I left the link.

Comment: Thats good thinking @GitGud